# C++ constexpr error statement showing error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, constexpr

Please help me with this error.

I am trying to make a sample that explains constexpr keyword in c++. I am using Visual Studio 2013.
Following is the code of my cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

const int sampleconstant = 5;


constexpr int constTest(void)
{
    return sampleconstant;
}
int main()
{

    std::cout << constTest();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This shows compile time error as follows:

Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I may be doing something silly here. But really can't figure out this error. Code looks ok to me. If any one can help me with error please help.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood the meaning of `constexpr` ... it means that the value of the function can be calculated at compile time. This is clearly not the case for `factorial`, since the value of `n` is not fixed at compile time.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions

Comment: Hi Markku K.  Thanks for the view. But I simplified the code above. The above modified code is showing same error. I think my understandings are ok about constexpr. But the above modified code is showing same error. Let me know if you still find some problem in code

Comment: **This version of your compiler does not support that feature** (and a quick search on Google or even SO would have told you that!).

Comment: @MarkkuK.: Not true (unless there was an edit in the grace period I didn't see?) - with the argument to `factorial` being the integer literal `4`, his code was absolutely fine.

Comment: @dyp: Tee hee hee. Anyway he said "Visual Studio 2013"; until he changes that...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Thanks a lot. You saved my time. This was a new topic for me. So I  was confused.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, quite true, I was the one who misunderstood `constexpr`!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As already told you, it is not supported on VS.

You can see at this link a list of featured supported by the compilers: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport

Comment: -1: That table is horrifically out of date. For one thing, it hasn't been "C++0x" for _three years_. For another, the data hasn't been updated since May last year. Finally, the feature _is_ supported by Visual Studio, just not the version that the OP is using.

Comment: I'm sorry for the fault, I googled to find this table and I didn't realized that was out of date.